# Prevent newer versions of SQL from building or executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My laptop is running SQL Server 2019, but my server is running an older version.

Is there a way I can configure my laptop database such that I can use SQL Server 2019, but have it fail to execute or compile SQL that is newer than a specific version, without installing two separate instances of SQL Server?

I.e. I would like to configure my database such that if STRING_AGG is executed, it will fail because I have set my database into something like a SQL Server 2016 mode.

Or any plugins that do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If both databases have compatibility level 130, I can run STRING_AGG on SQL Server 2019 but not 2016 @GordonLinoff

Comment: short answer - no, it cannot be guaranteed even with the compatibility level. And not only do you need to worry about versions, you need to consider edition functionality.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to install a named instance of the same version as your server on your laptop and use that to ensure compatibility with the production version